# PyQt5 ApplicationWindow in Qml gets blank screen

Tags: python, c++, pyqt, qml, pyqt5

I am trying to load a ApplicationWindow instance with PyQt5. I was reading about how it is done it C++ and this is the correct answer. How would I create this using PyQt5? The documentation in Python is a little different than that of C++.

```
#include <QGuiApplication>
#include <QQmlApplicationEngine>
#include <QQuickWindow>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);
QQmlApplicationEngine engine;
engine.load(QUrl("qml/window/main.qml"));
QObject *topLevel = engine.rootObjects().value(0);
QQuickWindow *window = qobject_cast<QQuickWindow *>(topLevel);
window->show();
return app.exec();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Very basic example:

`example.py`:

```
from PyQt5.QtCore import QUrl
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication
from PyQt5.QtQuick import QQuickView
import sys

app = QApplication(sys.argv)

view = QQuickView()
view.setSource(QUrl("example.qml"))
view.show()

app.exec()
```

`example.qml`:

```
import QtQuick 2.0

Rectangle {
    width: 300; height: 100
    color: "gray"

    Text {
        id: helloworld
        text: "Hello world!"
        color: "blue"
        font.pointSize: 32
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure about Linux but this doesn't work on Windows. I think you have to create a ApplicationEngine object in c++ in order to load it in QML. I'm just having a hard time converting to code to python.

Comment: @user2887117 if you use a QQuickView you don't need to create a QmlEngine yourself, QQuickView handles that for you - but you can also specify the engine to be used if you want to. Check out [Deploying QML Applications](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtquick/qtquick-deployment.html) - or the [QQuickView docs](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qquickview.html#QQuickView-2)

Comment: I wonder what the reason is that I keep getting a blank white screen. I am trying to load just a simple ApplicationWindow in qml.